# How to make a haunting ghost?

Tags: graphics, functions

How to make a harmless ghost (one that looks like a flying bed sheet)?

One can always make a [Ghost Curve](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=randomly+colored+ghost+curve).

Or one can define define a clever wiggly function with a random fluctuation.

My initial guess is a parabolic top with some sinusoidal bottom.

```
ghost[t_] = If[t > 0, {Sin[2 t Pi], Cos[2 t Pi]^2}, 
                {{Sin[2 Pi t], -0.2 Sin[8 Pi t]^2}}]
ParametricPlot[ghost[t], {t, -1, 1}]
```

[image]

and put some random oscillation to make it move.

Have anyone come across any better ghost in their shell (or notebook)?

### Pac-Ghost

A simple ghost from Pacman.

```
h = 1.0; w = 1.0;
x[t_, t0_] = Piecewise[{{w/2, 0 <= t < 1/8}, {-w (t - 1/4) 4, 
 1/8 <= t < 3/8}, {-w/2, 3/8 <= t < 5/8}, {w (t - 3/4) 4, 
 5/8 <= t < 7/8}, {w/2, 7/8 <= t < 1}}, w/2];
y[t_, t0_] = Piecewise[{{4 h t, 0 <= t < 1/8}, {h/2 + 2 w (1/4 - (4 t - 1)^2), 
 1/8 <= t < 3/8}, {-4 h (t - 1/2), 3/8 <= t < 5/8}, {-h/2 + 
  0.2 (Sin[8 (t - t0 - 3/2) Pi]^2 - Sin[8 (t0 - 3/2) Pi]^2), 
 5/8 <= t < 7/8}, {4 h (t - 1), 7/8 <= t < 1.0}}];

Animate[ParametricPlot[{x[t, t0], y[t, t0]}, {t, 0, 1}, 
  PlotRange -> {{-1, 1}, {-0.8, 1.2}}, 
  Epilog -> {Disk[{w/4, h/2}, w/10], Disk[{-w/4, h/2}, w/10]}]
,{t0, 0, 1, 0.1}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 14, accepted):

One approach can be using `BSplineFunction` which can take care of the smoothness of the ghost. Here I start from a triangle for the base shape and keep updating the ghost profile with a random fluctuation for the bottom part.

```
pt0 = {{-1, 0}, {0, 2}, {1, 0}};
c0 = BSplineFunction[pt0, SplineClosed -> True, SplineDegree -> 3];
a = Area[Polygon[c0[#] & /@ Range[0, 1, 0.01]]];
ListAnimate@Table[pt0 = c0[#]/a & /@ Range[0, 1, 0.02];
 pt1 = (# - Mean[pt0] + 
       (1 - HeavisideTheta[#[[2]]]) RandomReal[0.025 {-1, 1}, 2]) & /@ pt0;
 e0 = Mean@Select[pt1, #[[2]] > 0 &];
 c0 = BSplineFunction[pt1, SplineClosed -> True, SplineDegree -> 3];
 a = Area[Polygon[c0[#] & /@ Range[0, 1, 0.01]]];
 Graphics[{Gray, Polygon[c0[#]/a & /@ Range[0, 1, 0.01]], 
           White, Disk[e0 + {# 0.1, -0.05}, a/20] & /@ {-1, 1}}, 
           PlotRange -> {{-1, 1}, {-1, 1}}, AspectRatio -> 1, Background -> Black]
,{n, 100}]
```

[image]

Probably it can be done in three dimension as well starting from a pyramid.